# Chrome notifications appear bigger and off-screen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications

I have Windows 10 and the latest version of Chrome.
As of this morning, all desktop notifications from Chrome suddenly appear much bigger than before and off-screen. Meaning, they are not attached to the bottom right corner of the screen, but go over it and appear "cut". I do manage to drag the notification popup, but cannot take it to the left in order to see it in full. I've already tried to turn them off and back on, including restarting Chrome itself of course.

Comment: You might uninstall and reinstall Chrome (saving bookmarks).

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you have multiple screens and their resolution change (for example taking your laptop home and connecting to other screen).
You can restart or reset the resolution manually and it will go back to normal size.